# how to get the full querystring, or other options?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, query-string

Im working with querystrings and experience problems with it. i got different shipping providers and i do package tracking, so i show their tracking pages on "my" site in a iframe.

now the strange thing is that i only get the full querystring on one of the providers. one if the providers have a really long tracking url but two got pretty much the same.

i use this to catch the querystring

```
<% var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["tracking"]; %>
```

is there maybe another way to get the full querystring after my querystring `[tracking]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the solution: `string str = Request.QueryString.ToString();`